# Inverse Fourier transform of Specific function

Tags: fourier-transform

I am trying to take the inverse Fourier transform of the following function:
$$\left(1+\frac{b^2+a^2}{f^2}+\frac{b^2a^2}{f^4}\right)$$
where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers and $f$ is the frequency. So basically I want to get to the time data that gives this frequency spectrum. However Mathematica can't provide an answer and after working through I am left with $~\sin(\infty)~$ and $~\cos(\infty)~$terms which don't appear to cancel. Hoping someone knows some alternative method.

Thanks

Comment: What is the invariable of the function?

Comment: I assume $f$ is the variable.  In general, transform of the sum is the sum of the transforms.  In any case, all three terms have singularities as the transforms.  For example $1$ transform to a $\delta-$function.